# Redefining the environmental "make" command?

Tags: environment-variables, gnu-make, configure, hpc

I'm trying to install a program on a HPC cluster on which I do not have root access. I've been chasing a bunch of dependencies and trying to install them locally.

The original program requires mariadb, which apparently requires GLIBC 2.14/2.17 (cluster is on 2.12), which requires make 4.0 or higher (cluster has 3.81).

```
configure: error:
*** These critical programs are missing or too old: make bison python
*** Check the INSTALL file for required versions.
```

I've installed make 4.1 in a local directory, but cannot figure out how to point the configure file for GLIBC 2.35 towards that version of make.

Is there a way to redefine the environmental "make" command or to point a configure file towards a particular folder?

Answer (score 0):

Just point the path to the directory first... `export PATH=<dir_path_to_make>:${PATH}`

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! I tried adding the folder to path as you described ($PATH now shows /.../make4.1/bin), but the configure file doesn't seem to notice, and still spits out the same error: "configure: error:
*** These critical programs are missing or too old: make bison python
*** Check the INSTALL file for required versions."

Comment: Run `rehash`, check with `which make`, check what it is you are building does not reset PATH.

Comment: I ran `hash` (I think bash doesn't have rehash?) and `which make` now shows the intended make version: `/.../programs/make4.1/bin/make`, but the configure file for GLIBC still seems to be finding the system-wide make: `checking for gmake... gmake
checking version of gmake... 3.81, bad`

Comment: You should be smart enough to check whether `gmake` exists in the dirctory where you have put the new make, and if it does not exist, then symlink it. Secondly, did you configure make to be installed into a new directory, then ran `make install`, then update PATH for that new dir, rather than just build make and leave it there?

Comment: Thank you! I'm a bit new to this so clearly not smart enough to check for a `gmake` symlink (not realizing that gmake is usually present as a separate/linked command), but that was the last piece. I really appreciate walking me through these steps!

Comment: What can I say, `wibble!`.